# Filter a log file

Tags: awk, files, logs, filter

I tried to filter my log file by the functionality
For example:

```
195.xx.x.x - - [13/Apr/2017:09:60:xx +0200] "POST /userx/index.php?m=contacts&xxxx...
192.xx.x.x - - [13/Apr/2017:09:45:xx +0200] "POST /userx/index.php?m=customer&xxxx...
197.xx.x.x - - [13/Apr/2017:09:10:xx +0200] "POST /userx/index.php?m=meeting&xxxx...
197.xx.x.x - - [13/Apr/2017:09:20:xx +0200] "POST /userx/index.php?m=dashboard&xxxx...
```

In this case my functionalities are contacts,customer,meeting,dashboard
I try to ignore The welcome page that's by default. I used

```
awk '$7 !~ /m=dashboard/ ' log file
```

my question is If can I ignore more functionalities that are in a file ?

```
cat file:
dashboard
meeting
```

For to have just this lines:

```
195.xx.x.x - - [13/Apr/2017:09:60:xx +0200] "POST /userx/index.php?m=contacts
192.xx.x.x - - [13/Apr/2017:09:45:xx +0200] "POST /userx/index.php?m=customer
```

Comment: You can use a delimiter as in: `awk -F= '$NF != "dashboard"' log_file`  which should work

Comment: yest, but my questionis is If can I filter with words that are in a file x?

Comment: @SaraQuispe, can you elaborate your question and add the expected output?

Comment: use `grep -Fvf file log` if the keywords in `file` are unique in input file `log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed '/\//!{H;d};G;/m=\(.*\)\n.*\1/d;P;d' file log
```

Explanation: First read `file` with the filter keywords, then the logfile. Lines containing no `/` are interpreted to be keywords and appended to the hold space (`H`). Other lines get the hold space appended (`G`) and are deleted if the keyword after the `m=` is repeated in the keyword list (`/m=\(.*\)\n.*\1/d`). If not, it's printed without the appended hold space (`P`).

Comment: @Sara This solution will also remove lines with substrings of the given keywords, e.g. it will remove lines with `m=meeting`, if `meetings` is in the filter file. It can be adapted, if this is a problem. I hope an `sed` solution is okay for you.

Comment: thanks @Philippos , it's works just if my  request has this form /userx/index.php?m=contacts but no if is more long like that /userx/index.php?m=contacts&doajax=xxx&.. I don't know why?

Comment: Because it assumed the `m` parameter was the last one (you see the line break `\n` following the string match. If another parameter could follow you will have to modify the script to allow for either `&` or line feed by replacing `\n` with `[&\n]`: `sed '/\//!{H;d};G;/m=\(.*\)[&\n].*\1/d;P;d' file log` It's better to understand a script so you can adapt it to your needs. More questions?

Answer (score 0):

Since your question seems to make more sense now, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
awk -F= 'NR==FNR{l[$NF]=1; next} { if (!l[$NF]) print;}' ignore_words your_log_file
```

**Edit**

As Sundeep pointed out in the comment above, you could use grep as follow:

```
grep -Fvf ignore_words log_file
```

To see what the options `-Fvf` are used for, please consult `man grep` page.

Comment: thanks @val0x00ff , it's works just if my request has this form /userx/index.php?m=contacts but not if is more long like that /userx/index.php?m=contacts&doajax=xxx&.. I don't know why?

Comment: @SaraQuispe  you are changing your requirements constantly. This is not the way to ask a question and expect someone knows exactly what you mean. You are not getting the result you want because the `-F=` will have 2 columns and doesn't know which one to match.